# .net 5.0 resolve dependencies from a separate folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild

with two `.net 5.0` projects outputs `client` and `server`, each folder includes about 200 mb of the same dependencies dll files (managed),

how to put these common dlls in a separate folder `common` and force both `client.dll` and `server.dll` to resolve their dependencies from it so a space of redundant 200 mb is gained?

client and server have to stay separate.

client.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

    <PropertyGroup>
      <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
      <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
      <TargetFrameworks>net5.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
      <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
      <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
      <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64;x86</Platforms>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
      <OutputPath>..\..\release\client\</OutputPath>
      <AssemblyName>client</AssemblyName>
      <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
      <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    ...

</Project>
```

server.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
        <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
        <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
        <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64;x86</Platforms>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
        <OutputPath>..\..\release\server\</OutputPath>
        <AssemblyName>server</AssemblyName>
        <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
        <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    ...
    
</Project>
```

Comment: Won't client and server not live on different machines and not be able to share the same folder?

Comment: Show an excerpt of your `.csproj` files. Also are the dll's .NET assemblies or unmanaged code (e.g. C++ libs)?

Comment: @DaveShaw it is `client` or `client+server`

Comment: what about creating common.csproj ?